# How to use concerned with gem in rails 3 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Right now I am working on rails 3.0.0. I want to use concerned_with gem, please help me how to use that gem.

Comment: can you please look into this https://github.com/matid/concerned_with

Comment: you could also use this http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Concern